# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Icons not changing

Tags: unity, gnome, icons, themes

Here's what I did:

**Installed theme**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arc-theme
```

**Installed icons**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/icons
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arc-icons
```

Switched theme and icon using Unity Tweak Tool (I have since uninstalled this because I thought it was causing conflict or something with Gnome) and Gnome Tweak Tool.

Result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy9XD.png

I tried the stuff I found online such as:

```
$ dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
$ setsid unity
```

and

```
$ compiz --replace
```

Which is really weird because only one icon pack is working, Numix Circle, the rest are not working at all..

Comment: Yeah, only Numix Circle works (or did work, I'm using i3wm now) for me as well... I advise going to /usr/share/themes and/or /usr/share/icons and seeing if any of the themes/icons are broken.